# ERROR! the playbook: ansible_playbook.yml could not be found

Tags: ansible

I am getting this error when I try to run a playbook given by file `oracle19c_rdbmsinstall.yml`:

```
[t95bm75@la21t02rhel8 ansible]$ ansible-playbook oracle19c_rdbmsinstall.yml --step --ask-pass 
ERROR! the playbook: oracle19c_rdbmsinstall.yml could not be found
```

The file is in the path specified by Ansible config file's `library` parameter:

```
[t95bm75@la21t02rhel8 ansible]$ more ansible.cfg
[defaults]
inventory = /home/t95bm75/demo/ansible/inventory
library = /home/t95bm75/demo/ansible/OracleDBAwithAnsible/
roles_path = /etc/ansible/roles:/home/t95bm75/demo/ansible/OracleDBAwithAnsible/roles
#module_utils   = /usr/share/my_module_utils/
```

I verified, that the playbook file exists there:

```
[t95bm75@la21t02rhel8 OracleDBAwithAnsible]$ pwd /home/t95bm75/demo/ansible/OracleDBAwithAnsible
    
[t95bm75@la21t02rhel8 OracleDBAwithAnsible]$ ls -lt
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 t95bm75 ansible   71 Apr  7 15:03 oracle19c_rdbmsinstall.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 t95bm75 ansible 2364 Apr  7 15:03 README.md
drwxr-xr-x. 3 t95bm75 ansible   35 Apr  7 15:03 roles
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of duplicating questions, you can also [edit] your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651475/ansible-error-the-playbook-could-not-be-found) with the information presented here. That is exactly what was missing as debugging-details and is needed to reopen it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible Error the playbook could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651475/ansible-error-the-playbook-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

Given:

- `/home/t95bm75/demo/ansible/OracleDBAwithAnsible` is the folder where your playbook was found according to your console output
- `oracle19c_rdbmsinstall.yml` is the playboook file you want to run

Your prompt `[t95bm75@la21t02rhel8 ansible]$` indicates that your present-working-directory from which running the command is `ansible` and not the folder containing your playbook (i.e. `OracleDBAwithAnsible`).

#### Misconception

The [`library`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) key in config is explained in the docs.
It is the path to modules or plugins, see Ansible's Developer Guide, [Adding modules and plugins locally](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_locally.html):

> You can **extend** Ansible by adding custom *modules* or *plugins*.

The *modules* or *plugins* are only **extensions**. So the `library` path configured is used to load them additionally (as extension) to your playbook.

#### Solution

Try to find your playbook in the absolute path:

```bash
ls /home/t95bm75/demo/ansible/OracleDBAwithAnsible/oracle19c_rdbmsinstall.yml
```

Then run the ansible command using exactly this **absolute path**:

```bash
ansible-playbook /home/t95bm75/demo/ansible/OracleDBAwithAnsible/oracle19c_rdbmsinstall.yml --step
```

This way it does not matter in which present working directory you currently are when calling the command (`pwd` can be anything).

Comment: I had thought that the library variable would automatically path to the yml code.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Refoel Your intuition was misguided: [_modules_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)#Modules) loaded from the `library` and [_playbooks_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)#Playbooks) have different purposes. Please read the docs first ... I digested the difference and added links in my answer.

Comment: @Refoel and please read the [comments and links answering your duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651475/ansible-error-the-playbook-could-not-be-found#comment128332869_72651475) .. so we don't need to repeat ourselves (DRY).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to run ansible in the the `ansible` directory, while the `oracle19c_rdbmsinstall.yml` file is actually in `OracleDBAwithAnsible`